# Teradata - Comparing Varchar to decimal

Tags: sql, inner-join, teradata

I am very new to `Teradata` and `SQL` in general. I need to create a table by combining data from three tables. I was able to successfully join two of them. I am not able to write the joining condition for the third table properly. Here is the code:

```
select s.cola, s.colb, 
t.colc, t.cold,
u.cole, u.colf, u.colg, u.colh, u.coli, u.colj, u.colk, u.coll
from table1 s 
inner join table2 t
on s.colb = t.colc
inner join table3 u
on t.cold = cast(u.colm as decimal)
order by 3
where substr(cast(s.cola as varchar(10)),6,2) = 11 and substr(cast(s.cola as varchar(10)),1,4) = 2017 and substr(cast(s.cola as varchar(10)),9,2) between 06 and 10
```

The error I am getting is:

`[Teradata Database] [2620] The format or data contains a bad character.`

I think the problem is with the line: `on t.cold = cast(u.colm as decimal)`. The `u.colm` is of type `VARCHAR(50)` while `t.cold` is of type `DECIMAL(10, 0)`. I believe I have casted it properly. Please help.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's some bad data in `u.colm`.

Depending on your Teradata release you can check it using

```
WHERE u.colm > '' AND TRYCAST(u.colm as decimal(10,0)) ISNULL
```

or

```
WHERE u.colm > '' AND TO_NUMBER(u.colm) IS NULL
```

You can also use those in the join-condition, e.g.

```
on t.cold = trycast(u.colm as decimal(10,0))
```

Don't forget to add the precision of the decimal, as it defaults to `(5,0)`.

Your WHERE_condition is strange, what's the datatype of `s.cola`?
Seems it's a string with a date `yyyy-mm-dd` in it. Try

```
WHERE trycast(s.cola as date) between date '2017-11-06' and date '2017-11-10'
```

Finally the `ORDER BY` should be placed after `WHERE`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It turns out that `u.colm` has a few values which contains both alphabets and numbers. I fixed it by casting `t.cold` as `varchar(50)`. The `s.cola` is date, but the above line didn't work. Thank you for the correction on `order by`.

Comment: The date issue in `where` condition was resolved when I tried `cast` instead of `trycast`.