# Teradata - Adding preceding zero and casting as varchar(50)

Tags: sql, inner-join, teradata, on-clause

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
  s.cola, s.colb, t.colc, t.cold, u.cole, u.colf, u.colg, u.colh, u.coli, u.colj, u.colk, u.coll 
FROM table1 s
INNER JOIN table2 t
  ON s.colb = t.colc
INNER JOIN table3 u
  ON u.colm = CAST(t.cold AS varchar(50))
WHERE cast(s.cola as date) between date '2017-11-06' and date '2017-11-10'
ORDER BY 3
```

Here, in the last joining condition, `u.colm` is of type `varchar(50)` and `t.cold` is of type `decimal(10, 0)`. I cannot cast `u.colm` as `decimal(10, 0)` because some of the outdated values in that column are not purely numbers. Now, if I run the query as shown above, it will return a blank table because the common values in `u.colm` has a preceding/leading zero while `t.cold` doesn't have that zero. I tried the following:

1)  `on u.colm = '0' + cast(t.cold as varchar(50))`

This gave the error: 
`[Teradata Database] [2620] The format or data contains a bad character.`

2) `on u.colm = right('0000000000' + cast(t.cold as varchar(50)), 50)`

This gave the error:
`[Teradata Database] [9881] Function 'TD_RIGHT' called with an invalid number or type of parameters`

The question, answers and comments in [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47928199/4834108) will provide some more context. I am pretty new to Teradata and don't have much idea on how to resolve this issue. Kindly help.

Comment: Why don't you use my proposed way to remove the bad data before the join? `WHERE u.colm > '' AND TO_NUMBER(u.colm) IS NULL`. Is there a consistent number of leading zeroes? Can you show some existing data?

Comment: The table from which `u.colm` comes from has numbers that belong to three categories. The category which is supposed to match with `t.cold` has preceding zero  and are 10 digits in all cases. The `t.cold` values are all 9 digits since they don't have preceding zeros.

Comment: I am trying to incorporate your `where` clause.  I will update after that. Thank You.

Comment: @dnoeth : It looks like adding your `where` clause resolved the issue. Can you please post it as an answer so that I can accept it? Thank You.

Comment: It's the same WHERE I posted on your previous question :-)

Answer (score 2):

[I believe Teradata supports the `LPAD()` function](https://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_16_00/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035-1145-160K/xwo1472241148774.html), so you can use:

```
u.colm = lpad(t.cold, 10, '0')
```

Comment: It says: `[Teradata Database] [9881] Function 'LPAD' called with an invalid number or type of parameters`